# Grails - How do I get the value of a domain entity prop in a function of its parent class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have an abstract class in a groovy file:

**Implementation 1**

```
public abstract class Item {
  public String testStr;

  public String getBigTestStr(){
      String s = "___" + this.testStr;
      return s;
  }
}
```

Which is inherited by

```
class Material extends Item {
  public String testStr;

  static marshalling = {
    detail {
        includes "bigTestStr"
    }
    summary {
        includes "bigTestStr"
    }
  }

  static mapping = {
    table   'materialset'
    id       column: 'NODEID'
    testStr  column: 'MATERIALTYPE'
    version  false
  }
}
```

The idea is that hitting the endpoint for a material will return the return value of `Item.bigTestStr()`. However, when I trace through `Item.bigTestStr()`, the debug's variables table shows a value for `this.testStr`, but is null when it is added to `s`. See here:

[image]

I tried taking the `testStr` property out of `Material`

**Implementation 2**

```
class Material extends Item {

  static marshalling = {
    detail {
        includes "bigTestStr"
    }
    summary {
        includes "bigTestStr"
    }
  }

  static mapping = {
    table   'materialset'
    id       column: 'NODEID'
    testStr  column: 'MATERIALTYPE'
    version  false
  }
}
```

but I still get the same problem.

[image]

For both implementations the endpoint returns

```
{
  bigTestStr: ____null
}
```

How can I get the actual value of `Material.testStr` to be used by the function in its parent class?

**UPDATE**

As Emmanuel pointed out, Implementation 2 is the right way to use properties from a parent class. However, this implementation does not seem to work with mapping the parent class' properties to a database column. So the real question is: **How can I get `Material.testStr` to map to a database column?**

Comment: Grails version 2.3.8 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is in how you initialized your `Material` instance. Here's an example:

```
public abstract class Item {
  public String testStr

  public String getBigTestStr(){
      "___$testStr"
  }
}

class MaterialA extends Item {
  public String testStr

  static marshalling = {
    detail {
        includes 'bigTestStr'
    }
    summary {
        includes 'bigTestStr'
    }
  }

  static mapping = {
    table   'materialset'
    id       column: 'NODEID'
    testStr  column: 'MATERIALTYPE'
    version  false
  }
}

class MaterialB extends Item {

  static marshalling = {
    detail {
        includes 'bigTestStr'
    }
    summary {
        includes 'bigTestStr'
    }
  }

  static mapping = {
    table   'materialset'
    id       column: 'NODEID'
    testStr  column: 'MATERIALTYPE'
    version  false
  }
}
```

Shown above are three classes `Item`, `MaterialA`, and `MaterialB`. The two material classes simulate your two tests: `MaterialA` has a `testStr` property, while `MaterialB` inherits a property with the same name from `Item` instead. Here's what happens when instances of both classes are initialized and `getBigTestStr()` is tested:

```
new MaterialA(testStr: 'Hello').with {
    assert bigTestStr == '___null'
}

new MaterialB(testStr: 'Hello').with {
    assert bigTestStr == '___Hello'
}
```

In short, your second approach, inheriting the property, works. A super class does not (and should not) have access to anything in its subclasses. It doesn't even *know* about its subclasses. The approach works because initializing `testStr` in an instance of `MaterialB` actually initializes the inherited property from `Item`; which of course is accessible within the `Item` class.

In your case, Grails is initializing the instances for you using the values stored in the database. So I'd check your database.

## Update

Here's an example using a trait rather than an abstract class:

```
public trait Item {
  String testStr

  public String getBigTestStr(){
      "___$testStr"
  }
}

class Material implements Item {

  static marshalling = {
    detail {
        includes 'bigTestStr'
    }
    summary {
        includes 'bigTestStr'
    }
  }

  static mapping = {
    table   'materialset'
    id       column: 'NODEID'
    testStr  column: 'MATERIALTYPE'
    version  false
  }
}

new Material(testStr: 'Hello').with {
    assert bigTestStr == '___Hello'
}
```

This makes it so that there's no need for an `Item` table.

Comment: I was able to set the value of `testStr` in a constructor for `Material`, so you are right that my problem is definitely database related. 


The `MaterialType` collumn is definitely populated in every row. I guess my real problem is that mapping the value from the column to `testStr` seems to not be working. 

Do I have to do anything in `Item` to map that property? I can't map it directly to a table, since other child classes will use different tables.

Comment: By default, when you remove a property from a domain class its database column is not removed. When `Material` had a `testStr` property there where two `test_str` columns in the database: one in the `item` table and another in the `material` table. If you populated the database then, and later removed the `testStr` from `Material` you'd still have both `test_str` columns, but the one in the `material` table would be ignored. If this is the case, you can fix it my copying `material.test_str` to item.test_str with a database query. Then drop the `material.test_str` column.

Comment: Note that I'm going by what you said about having a table per sub-class even though your `Item` example suggests you're using table-per-hierarchy; meaning the super class and its sub-classes share the same table.

Comment: Perhaps that I am trying to do something that is not entirely what grails was designed for. I am not using GORM for table creation at all. Also, there is no `Item` table in the database, nor is there supposed to be. The only reason I want it, is so that I do not have to manage the same properties and functions on every subclass of `item`.

Comment: If you want to reuse properties and methods, a good way to do that is with Groovy traits. But, you'll need Grails 2.4 or greater. If you make `Item` a trait then it's no longer a domain class and doesn't need a table. This also means `Item.groovy` must be moved from grails-app/domains/... to src/main/groovy/...